# HTML Nested tables with valign in IE not previewing properly

Tags: html, css, email

I can't seem to align the bottom-right table within a table cell to the bottom in IE. (despite aligning the table cell with vertical-align:"bottom" AND declaring valign="bottom". Bug?

Also note. this is for an email so CSS declarations in the head are basically off-limit. 
It previews with the table that has stacked list vertically aligned to the top.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="10" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="258" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666666;"><table width="258" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="258" height="15" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666666;"><span style="font-size:18px; line-height:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:#e48828;"><br />
                        Curabitur egestas lorem a nisl aliquet.</span><br />
                        <br />
                        Fusce faucibus lorem vel arcu aliquet rutrum. Etiam semper, urna ut scelerisque tristique, dolor sapien porta justo, rutrum tempor ipsum. <br />
                        <br />
                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="10" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="#" width="10" height="10" alt=" " style="display:block;"/></td>
                                <td width="10" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="223" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color: #e48828;">Etiam sem elit, venenatis sit.</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        <td width="10" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="11" bgcolor="#eeefef" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="271" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="271" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100" height="152" bgcolor="#B2B3B7">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="10" bgcolor="#eeefef" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="151" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666666;"><br />
                                    <span style="font-size:12px; line-height:18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#005696;"><strong>Phasellus sed ipsum vel augue.</strong><br />
                                    </span> <span style="font-size:10px; line-height:12px;">Aliquam suscipit libero non orci tincidunt nec convallis. <br />
                                    </span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="271" height="12" bgcolor="#eeefef">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="271" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="vertical-align:bottom;"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25" height="15" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="10" height="15" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="10" height="15" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="226" height="15" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="10" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="#" width="10" height="10" alt=" " style="display:block;"/></td>
                                <td width="10" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="226" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color: #e48828;">Etiam sem elit, venenatis sit.</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="10" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="#" width="10" height="10" alt=" " style="display:block;"/></td>
                                <td width="10" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="226" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color: #e48828;">Etiam sem elit, venenatis sit.</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        <td width="10" bgcolor="#eeefef" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10" height="15" bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #b2ccdf;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="258" height="15" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #b2ccdf;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="10" height="15" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #b2ccdf;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="11" height="15" bgcolor="#eeefef" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #eeefef;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="271" height="15" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #b2ccdf;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="10" height="15" bgcolor="#eeefef" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #eeefef;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: screenshot of ie problem]

Comment: If it's for an email template then why does it have to work in IE?

Comment: Because IE would be used to render in outlook clients and also for web clients like hotmail, gmail, etc

Comment: What happens if you remove the 1005 height from the table in this line <td width="271" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="vertical-align:bottom;"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%"> . I don't have IE to test right now.

Comment: it doesn't change. I was trying to "force" IE to render the table at 100%, but it renders 100% of it's content not container. (the td)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's a bug.

The table in this line:

```
<td width="271" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;"><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

doesn't need more vertical space to render, so it gets "closed" higher than the left side. Your valign'ed table is correctly aligned, but the td it vertically aligns to is only large enough to contain it, so there's no actual effect of the valign.

I would solve this by using only ONE table, with rowspans and colspans as needed, insted of the countless nested tables you now have...